# Private server created by Nexus failed to be the proxy of central repository

Tags: maven, nexus

I add this code in settting.xml

```
<mirror>
    <id>Public Repositories</id>
    <mirrorOf>central</mirrorOf>
    <name>Public Repositories</name>
    <url>http://10.97.19.51:8081/nexus/content/groups/public/</url> 
</mirror>
```

Then when I execute: mvn clean compile, it failed!

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building second 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ second ---
[INFO] Deleting E:\EclipseWorkspace\second\target
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ second ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory E:\EclipseWorkspace\second\src\main\resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ second ---
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 0.459 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2015-12-22T17:47:20+08:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 8M/155M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project second: Execution default-compile of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile failed: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failure to find com.google.collections:google-collections:jar:1.0 in http://11.97.19.55:8081/nexus/content/groups/public/ was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of Public Repositories has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginResolutionException
```

the following is my configuration of my repository in Nexus.

[image]

[image]

Anybody know the reason? Thank you!!

Comment: add your screenshots to your question as text!

Comment: also elaborate on what dependency or repository you are trying to proxy with your nexus and add the information to your question. (the nexus repo-config could be a screenshot in this case).

Answer (score 1):

Make your nexus a proxy for everything by:

```
<mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>
```

Make sure you have the remote repository configured as `proxy` in your nexus insance. (Maybe check it with the browsing feature of your nexus).
Make sure you've added the remote repository to the group `public` so it is accessible for maven.

Comment: either as proxy of central repository or all remote repository is not Okay.

Comment: then uninstall your nexus?! It is the very purpose of a nexus (or any other artifactory) to proxy as much as possible and by that reduce load on public repos.

Comment: I delete the repository folder in .m2 and try again, it works!